# Rules for MySQL type conversion

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering what the rules are for mysql type conversions are. e.g.

`select foo/2 from table` seems to  yield a decimal if the `foo` column is an int. `select sum(foo) from table` gives the sum(foo) column back as a double if `foo` is a float. `select i*i from table` gives a bigint if i is an int.

What are the rules for the type conversion here when using common operators such as +-/* or aggregates such as sum/avg ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of type conversion are quite straightforward. Quoting from the [MySQL Manual :: Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html):

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly.
>
> The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations:
>
> - If one or both arguments are `NULL`, the result of the comparison is `NULL`, except for the `NULL`-safe `<=>` equality comparison operator. For `NULL <=> NULL`, the result is `true`. No conversion is needed.
> - If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings.
> - If both arguments are integers, they are compared as integers.
> - Hexadecimal values are treated as binary strings if not compared to a number.
> - If one of the arguments is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more ODBC-friendly. Note that this is not done for the arguments to `IN()` To be safe, always use complete datetime, date, or time strings when doing comparisons. For example, to achieve best results when using `BETWEEN` with date or time values, use `CAST()` to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type.
> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

In the case of arithmetic operators, the result is determined according to the following rules. Quoting from the [MySQL Manual :: Arithmetic Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/arithmetic-functions.html)

> - In the case of `-`, `+`, and `*`, the result is calculated with `BIGINT` (64-bit) precision if both arguments are integers.
> - If one of the arguments is an unsigned integer, and the other argument is also an integer, the result is an unsigned integer.
> - If any of the operands of a `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, `%` is a real or string value, the precision of the result is the precision of the argument with the maximum precision.
> - In division performed with `/`, the scale of the result when using two exact values is the scale of the first argument plus the value of the div_precision_increment system variable (which is 4 by default). For example, the result of the expression `5.05 / 0.014` has a scale of six decimal places `(360.714286)`.

Then for aggregate functions, the following applies. Quoting from the [MySQL Manual :: Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html):

> For numeric arguments, the variance and standard deviation functions return a `DOUBLE` value. The `SUM()` and `AVG()` functions return a `DECIMAL` value for exact-value arguments (integer or `DECIMAL`), and a `DOUBLE` value for approximate-value arguments (`FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`).

Comment: While that answers a lot, it doesn't say a lot about e.g. 1/2 yielding a decimal, or i*i yielding a bigint

Comment: @Anonym: Updated my answer with rules on arithmetic operators.